# Will I still have all my data and saves and if I get a new GTA disk?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

The disk is scratched and I was just wondering that, if I get a new disk, will I still have all my data and saves?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes.

Your data is saved to your online account.